# Change directory of Android Studio project

Tags: android, android-studio

For months I have been coding my project in its default location (for example "C:\aaa\bbb\project") and everytime I compiled it (generate the apk) or everytime I had to open the project in Android studio everything worked just fine.

Today I had to move the project to a new directory "C:\zzz\project" so I closed "Android Studio" and moved all the project's files and removed it from the old location. Now, when I open "Android Studio" and I go "Open" I can open my project, no problems. But when I try to compile (build the apk) it shows many errors and in the messages it clearly says the compiler is still looking for files in the old place.

I moved the project back to the original location "C:\aaa\bbb\project" and everything worked just fine. So my question is this: if I need to backup this project, move it to another directory... how do I make sure I wont face the problem I reported above? I am pretty sure Android Studio for some stupid reason hard coded the absolute directory path of the project in many files, instead of using relative paths. So what is the right way to move a project to another drive, computer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do a "Build->Clean Project" before and after attempting a move.  That's probably all you really need to do.

I couldn't replicate your experience, but here's what I'm getting at:

- With the original project open in Android Studio, select `Build->Clean Project` from the menu first. Wait for the cleaning to finish. (ala "Gradle Invocation Finished" toast).
- Close Android Studio

Then copy the folder to the new destination

`xcopy "c:\aaa\bbb\project" "c:\zzz\project\" /s /e`

After doing the folder copy, delete the .idea and .gradle folders from the destination folder.

```
cd c:\zzz\project
rmdir /s .idea
rmdir /s .gradle
```

Then:

- Open the project with Android Studio in its new location.
- Select Build->Clean Project from the menu first (ala "Gradle Invocation Finished" toast).
- Then Build->Make Project to initiate a full clean build. Wait for the cleaning to finish.

You may also want to refer to the common Android Studio .gitignore file for hints of other files you don't need to sync between directories: https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/main/Android.gitignore

You could also use the .gitignore file along with syncing your project to Github. The re-clone it directly into a new folder.